# What is the most efficient way of mapping multiple functions to a vector of strings in R?

Tags: r, performance, purrr

I have a list of filenames which live in the same sub-directory, spanning a few different file extensions. My goal is to extract each of the file names without their full paths and without their extensions, which I can successfully do in the following way:

```
req_libraries <- c("dplyr", "purrr", "stringr")
lapply(req_libraries, require, character.only = TRUE)

file_list <- c("dir/folder/city_a.csv",
               "dir/folder/ city_b.xlsx",
               "dir/folder/city_c .csv")

target_names <- file_list %>%
  map(~ str_split(.x, pattern = "/")[[1]]) %>%
  map(~ tail(.x, 1)) %>%
  map(~ str_split(.x, pattern = "\\.")[[1]][1]) %>%
  map(~ trimws(.x, which = "both")) %>%
  unlist() %>%
  tibble()

target_names
```

This is fit for purpose, but I am curious about how best I can streamline my chain of functions. I'm confident that there is an easy way of achieving this, perhaps with a different function from the `map_*()` collection, but I've not had much success.

Thanks!

EDIT: some of you have made some really useful suggestions involving carrying out all of these steps in one go, and they work well. But, if in another scenario I *had* to map a series of functions to the same vector, what's the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `basename` to get only the filenames and `file_path_sans_ext` to get it without extension.

```
trimws(tools::file_path_sans_ext(basename(file_list)))
#[1] "city_a" "city_b" "city_c"
```

Or keep it in base R :

```
trimws(sub('\\..*', '', basename(file_list)))
```

Comment: Thanks Ronak! This is really useful - I hadn't heard of basename or file_path_sans_ext but these will definitely come in handy.. Say I was loyal to the method of mapping multiple functions to my list, as in the question, do you know if there is a way of doing the series of mappings more efficiently?

Comment: @SamB Do you want to use pipes for this? You can use `file_list %>% basename() %>% tools::file_path_sans_ext() %>% trimws` if that is the case.

Answer (score 3):

If you use a capturing group in `gsub`, this is a one-liner:

```
tibble(files = trimws(gsub("^.*/(.*)[.].*$", "\\1", file_list)))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 1
#>   files 
#>  <chr> 
#> 1 city_a
#> 2 city_b
#> 3 city_c
```

The regex breaks down like this:

- `^.*/` Means "match anything from the start of the string to the last foward slash"
- `(.*)[.]` means "now capture anything until the final period"
- `.*$` means "match anything else until the end of the string"

Comment: Thanks Allan! That's really helpful - I sometimes find regex a bit of a visual onslaught, but you've broken it down nicely. Say I was loyal to the method of mapping multiple functions to my list, as in the question, is there a way of doing the series of mappings more efficiently?